# get user latest visit date each month even its null by grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Data source

| User ID | Visit Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:29:15 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 12:30:11 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 12:31:01 |
| 2 | 2020-05-01 12:31:14 |

## Problem

I got user's visit data and im trying to get their last visit for each month, have been trying to join the data source with `generate_series('2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-12-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month')` but what i got is only 1 user for each month, do you guys have an idea how to achieve this

### Expected Result

| Month | User ID | Visit Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 12:29:15 |
| 2 | 1 | null |
| 3 | 1 | null |
| 4 | 1 | 2020-04-01 12:31:01 |
| .... |  |  |
| 12 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| ... |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | 2020-05-01 12:31:14 |
| ... and so on |  |  |

and i need advice im trying to do sub query for this result to mark user as retention if he havent visit back like below result, if u guys have better query to do this it will be appreciate

| Month | User ID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FIRST |
| 2 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 3 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 4 | 1 | REACTIVATE |
| .... |  |  |
| 12 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| ... |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | FIRST |
| 6 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 7 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 8 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 9 | 2 | null |
| ... and so on |  |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate the rows using a `cross join`.  Then you can get the last visit in various ways:

```
select u.user_id, gs.yyyymm, s.last_visit_date
from (select distinct user_id from source s) u cross join
     generate_series('2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-12-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month'
                    ) gs(yyyymm) left join lateral
     (select max(s.visit_date) as last_visit_date
      from source s
      where s.user_id = u.user_id and
            s.visit_date >= gs.yyyymm and
            s.visit_date < gs.yyyymm + interval '1 month'
     ) s
     on 1=1;
```

Comment: thanks it works but i need an advice if i get the data its gonna affect to performance, actually what im trying to get is to marked user as retention each month for 3 month if he havent visit back, do you know something to make it better ? i already update my question

Comment: @KiraKatou . . . Your comment sounds like a different question.  Please ask that as a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69201857/5351583 i already put it as new question, kindly check it