# marked user with label by time for each month

Tags: sql, postgresql

### Data source

| User ID | Visit Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 12:29:15 |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 12:30:11 |
| 1 | 2020-04-01 12:31:01 |
| 2 | 2020-05-01 12:31:14 |

## Problem

I need advice im trying to do sub query for this result to mark user as retention if they havent visit back for 3 month. i using this query for the data to get user's latest visit each month includes null

```
select u.user_id, gs.yyyymm, s.last_visit_date
from (select distinct user_id from source s) u cross join
     generate_series('2021-01-01'::timestamp, '2021-12-01'::timestamp, interval '1 month'
                    ) gs(yyyymm) left join lateral
     (select max(s.visit_date) as last_visit_date
      from source s
      where s.user_id = u.user_id and
            s.visit_date >= gs.yyyymm and
            s.visit_date < gs.yyyymm + interval '1 month'
     ) s
     on 1=1;
```

but i think its really affect to performance if user keep increasing, do you guys have any advice to achieve result like below?

### Expected Result

| Month | User ID | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FIRST |
| 2 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 3 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 4 | 1 | REACTIVATE |
| .... |  |  |
| 12 | 1 | null |
| 1 | 2 | null |
| ... |  |  |
| 5 | 2 | FIRST |
| 6 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 7 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 8 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 9 | 2 | null |
| ... and so on |  |  |

or it could be like this

| Month | First | Retention | Reactiavate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 5 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 6 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 7 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... and so on |  |  |  |

Comment: From your description you only need flags 'FIRST', 'RETENTION' and 'REACTIVATE'. Do you need month number as well?

Comment: Shouldn't the year in visit date in your data source be 2021 according to your query and the results?

Comment: please explain the logic briefly and provide few valid sample data and expected output based on given sample data.

Comment: what happens for user id 1 on months 5, 6, 7 & 8?

Comment: Can I suppose, that on the visit table are just inserts. Not delete and update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution have some reasonable requirements, but I can work without it (the price is some performance).

I built some helper tables what is autofilled with trigger.
The requirement is, that `UPDATE` or `DELETE` isn't allowed on *visit* table.

*mst_user* table stores distinct *user_id*-s and it's *first_visit*.
*user_monthly_visit* table stores the last and the first *visit_date* pro *user_id* and *month*.

#### TABLES

```
CREATE TABLE mst_user (
  id BIGINT,
  first_visit TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT pk_mst_user PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE visit (
  user_id BIGINT, 
  visit_date TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT visit_user_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES mst_user (id)
);

CREATE TABLE user_monthly_visit (
  user_id BIGINT,
  month DATE,
  first_visit_this_month TIMESTAMP,
  last_visit_this_month TIMESTAMP,
  CONSTRAINT pk_user_monthly_visit PRIMARY KEY (user_id, month),
  CONSTRAINT user_monthly_visit_user_fkey FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES mst_user (id)
);

CREATE INDEX ix_user_monthly_visit_month ON user_monthly_visit(month);
```

#### TRIGGER

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trf_visit()  RETURNS trigger
  VOLATILE
AS $xx$

DECLARE
  l_user_id       BIGINT;
  l_row          RECORD;
  l_user_monthly_visit user_monthly_visit;
BEGIN
  IF (tg_op = 'INSERT')
  THEN
    l_row := NEW;
    INSERT INTO mst_user(id, first_visit) VALUES (l_row.user_id, l_row.visit_date)
    ON CONFLICT(id) DO UPDATE SET first_visit = LEAST(mst_user.first_visit, l_row.visit_date);
    
    INSERT INTO user_monthly_visit(user_id,month,first_visit_this_month,last_visit_this_month) VALUES (l_row.user_id,date_trunc('month',l_row.visit_date),l_row.visit_date,l_row.visit_date) 
    ON CONFLICT(user_id,month) DO UPDATE SET first_visit_this_month = LEAST(user_monthly_visit.first_visit_this_month,l_row.visit_date),
    last_visit_this_month = GREATEST(user_monthly_visit.last_visit_this_month,l_row.visit_date);
  ELSE
    RAISE EXCEPTION 'UPDATE and DELETE arent allowed!';
  END IF;
  RETURN l_row; 
END;
$xx$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER trig_visit
  BEFORE INSERT OR DELETE OR UPDATE ON visit
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE trf_visit();
```

#### TESTDATA

```
INSERT INTO visit (user_id, visit_date)
VALUES (1, '20200101 122915');
INSERT INTO visit (user_id, visit_date)
VALUES (1, '20200102 123011');
INSERT INTO visit (user_id, visit_date)
VALUES (1, '20200401 123101');
INSERT INTO visit (user_id, visit_date)
VALUES (2, '20200501 123114');
```

#### QUERY

```
SELECT mnt AS month, user_id,
CASE WHEN first_visit IS NULL OR first_visit> yyyymm + INTERVAL '1 month' THEN NULL
  WHEN first_visit_this_month = first_visit THEN 'FIRST'
  WHEN first_visit_this_month IS NULL AND last_three_month + INTERVAL '3 month' >= yyyymm THEN 'RETENTION'
  WHEN first_visit_this_month IS NOT NULL THEN 'REACTIVATE'
  ELSE NULL
END user_type
FROM
(SELECT date_part('month', gs.yyyymm)::INTEGER AS mnt, gs.yyyymm, u.id user_id, umv.first_visit_this_month, umv.last_visit_this_month, u.first_visit,
GREATEST(
  LAG(last_visit_this_month) OVER w,
  LAG(last_visit_this_month,2) OVER w,
  LAG(last_visit_this_month,3) OVER w
) last_three_month
FROM 
  generate_series('2020-01-01'::TIMESTAMP, '2020-12-01'::TIMESTAMP, INTERVAL '1 month') gs(yyyymm)
  CROSS JOIN mst_user u
  LEFT JOIN user_monthly_visit umv on (umv.user_id=u.id AND umv.month = gs.yyyymm)
  WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY u.id ORDER BY gs.yyyymm)  
) monthly_visit
ORDER BY user_id,mnt;
```

#### RESULT

| month | user_id | user_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | FIRST |
| 2 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 3 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 4 | 1 | REACTIVATE |
| 5 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 6 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 7 | 1 | RETENTION |
| 8 | 1 | (null) |
| 9 | 1 | (null) |
| 10 | 1 | (null) |
| 11 | 1 | (null) |
| 12 | 1 | (null) |
| 1 | 2 | (null) |
| 2 | 2 | (null) |
| 3 | 2 | (null) |
| 4 | 2 | (null) |
| 5 | 2 | FIRST |
| 6 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 7 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 8 | 2 | RETENTION |
| 9 | 2 | (null) |
| 10 | 2 | (null) |
| 11 | 2 | (null) |
| 12 | 2 | (null) |

Answer (score 0):

restating your question so it is clearer for me:
for any given month, the user is classified as `first`, `retention` or `reactivate` based on the following criteria

1. first: month of first visit
2. retention: within 3 months since previous visit
3. reactivate: month of visit & no visit in prior month

If I understood this correctly, you can get the first desired result with the following query

**Schema (PostgreSQL v13)**

```
create table visits (user_id int, visit_at timestamp);
insert into visits values
(1, '2020-01-01 12:29:15'),
(1, '2020-01-02 12:30:11'),
(1, '2020-04-01 12:31:01'),
(2, '2020-05-01 12:31:14');
```

---

**Query**

```
WITH trange AS (
SELECT
  user_id
, DATE_TRUNC('month', min(visit_at)) visit_from
, DATE_TRUNC('month', max(visit_at)) + interval '3 month' visit_to
FROM visits
GROUP BY 1
)
, monthly_visits AS (
SELECT DISTINCT 
  user_id
, DATE_TRUNC('month', visit_at) visit_month
FROM visits
)
SELECT
  trange.user_id
, DATE(m) report_month
, CASE 
    WHEN visit_from = m THEN 'FIRST'
    WHEN visit_month = m AND LAST_VALUE(visit_month) OVER w IS NULL THEN 'REACTIVATE'
    WHEN m <= MAX(visit_month) OVER w + INTERVAL '3 MONTH' THEN 'RETENTION'

  ELSE NULL END user_type
FROM trange
LEFT JOIN LATERAL GENERATE_SERIES(visit_from, visit_to, '1 month') m(m) 
           ON true
LEFT JOIN monthly_visits 
       ON monthly_visits.user_id = trange.user_id 
      AND monthly_visits.visit_month = m.m
WINDOW w AS (
  PARTITION BY trange.user_id 
  ORDER BY m.m 
  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
);
```

| user_id | report_month | user_type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z | FIRST |
| 1 | 2020-02-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 1 | 2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 1 | 2020-04-01T00:00:00.000Z | REACTIVATE |
| 1 | 2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 1 | 2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 1 | 2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 2 | 2020-05-01T00:00:00.000Z | FIRST |
| 2 | 2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 2 | 2020-07-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |
| 2 | 2020-08-01T00:00:00.000Z | RETENTION |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/)